# Implement different serializing strategy for HTTP methods

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

With the model and serialzier listed below:

```py
# Django Model class
class Model(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


# DRF serializer class
class ModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ["id", "name"]
        model = Model
```

How to implement the serializer to accept and validate the `id` field for `HTTP POST` requests (it should be **unique** and **at most 10 characters**) but for `PUT` requests the **unique** validation should be skipped and just be checked `len(id) <= 10`.

I am looking for an idiomatic, clean and efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Idiotmatic, clean & efficient. Those are my favorites.
This should be readable enough.

```
# DRF serializer class
class ModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ["id", "name"]
        model = Model

    def validate_id(self, invalidated_id):
        request = self.context['request']
        # do logic based on request type and invalidated_id
```

```
# views.py
def my_weird_func(request, **kwrags):
    myModelInstance = kwargs['id'] # or whatever, this is a demonstration
    serializer = ModelSerializer(myModelInstance, context={'request': request})
    
    return Response('This is what're expecting')
```

Comment: I did it `ModelSerializer(data=request.data, context={"request": request})`, but accessing `self.context["request"]` raises `KeyError`.